# HERE Places API: incorrect data in response

Tags: here-api

We’ve found a problem with a response we get using a /places/v1/autosuggest request with the Places API. Request: https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/autosuggest?app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&at=52.379189%2C4.899431&cs=places&q=Empire+S&result_types=place

We search for the Empire State Building in New York (landmark-attraction) and get this response, please check:
http://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/autosuggest?at=52.379189%2C4.899431&q=Empire+State+Building&result_types=place&cs=places&Accept-Language=en-US%2Cen%3Bq%3D0.5&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg#

You’ll see the title and vicinity are correct, but if you look at the “href" and “id" you can see these aren’t, as those are for a restaurant named "State Grill and Bar":

href: http://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/places/840dr5ru-f494d331f0204d89bef762a8fdc04049;context=Zmxvdy1pZD00ZDkxN2QwNC03ODYwLTUzNGUtOTE4ZS04MjFlZTBmMmUxNjFfMTU1MjM0MzYyMDE3M18zODcyXzIxNjAmcmFuaz0wJmNzPXBsYWNlcw?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg

id: 840dr5ru-f494d331f0204d89bef762a8fdc04049

Does anyone know why we get the wrong href and id for the place, is this something on HERE's end?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reporting this issue. Our team is already on it. We shall keep you updated once the problem is fixed. You can also report wrong content using the MapCreator portal: https://mapcreator.here.com/

**This problem has been fixed.**

Comment: No problem, it's good to know it's a bug. I will also have a look at the link in case we'll need it again. Looking forward to see it fixed and thanks for the quick response.

Comment: I don't know how long this normally takes, but It's been a month now and unfortunately the bug (wrong href and id for the place) is still there.

Comment: We have verified that the bug has been fixed.